# Is this shortcut for modulo by a constant (C) valid? IF (A mod 2^n) > C: { -C}

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, modulo

Looking to do modulo operator, `A mod K` where...

- K is a uint32_t constant, is not a power of two, and I will be using it over and over again.
- A is a uint32_t variable, possibly as much as ~2^13 times larger than K.
- The ISA does not have single cycle modulo or division instructions. (8-bit micro)

The naive approach seems to coincide with the naive approach to division; repeat subtraction until underflow, then keep the remainder. This would obviously have fairly bad worst case performance, but would work for any A and K.

A [known fast approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Performance_issues) *which works well for a K that is some power of two*, is to logical AND with that power of two -1.

From Wikipedia...
`A % 2^n == A & (2^n - 1)`

My knee jerk reaction is to use these two things together, and I'm wondering if that is valid?

Specifically, I figure I can use the power of two mod trick to narrow the worst case for the above subtraction method. In other words, quickly mod *to the nearest power of two above my constant*, then subtract my constant if necessary. Here's the code that is in the actual question, fully expanded.

```py
A = A AND (2^n - 1) # MOD A to the next higher power of two
if A > K:     # See if we are still larger than our constant
    A -= K    # If so, subtract. We now must be lower.
##################
# A = A MOD K ???
##################
```

On inspection, this should always work, and should always be fast, since the next power of two greater than K should always be such that 2K will be larger. That is, `K < 2^n < 2K` meaning I should only ever need one extra test, and then possibly one subtraction.

...but this seems too simple. If it worked, I'd expect to have seen it before. But I can't find an example. I can't find a counter example either though. [I have](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=modulo%20constant) [checked](http://www.piclist.com/techref/microchip/math/div/index.htm) [the usual](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) [places](https://www.jjj.de/fxt/#fxtbook).  What am I missing?

Comment: `A = A AND 2^n # MOD A to the next higher power of two` How is this mod? This will reset all bits of `A` to `0`. Maybe it should be `A = A mod (2^n-1)`

Comment: Good catch. It was a typo. It has been corrected.

Comment: -Charlie Is it still not clear?

Comment: I'm still reading it and checking some things. Though, I think I get what you're saying. I will probably mark it as correct once I'm done fact checking everything. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't combine both the approaches. First understand why does the below equation holds true.

```
A % p == A & (p - 1), where p = 2^n
```

`p` will have exactly `1` set bit in it's binary representation, say it's position is `x`.

So all the numbers which have atleast one set bit in a position greater than `x`, are all divisible by `p`, that is why performing `AND` with `p-1` would give all set bits less than `2^x`, which is same as performing `mod`

But that isn't the case when `p` is not a power of `2`.

If that didn't made sense, then take for example:

```
A = 18 = 10010,
K = 6 = 110,
A % K = 0
```

According to your approach, you will perform `AND` operation with `A` and `7 (= 2^3-1)`, resulting in `2`, which is not the value of `MOD`.

Comment: Currently looking for any prime where the bits below some large 2^n are all `0`, in a (desperate?) attempt to disprove "So all the numbers which have at least one set bit in a position greater than `x`, are all divisible by `p`" It's not looking good so far though.

Comment: @Charlie The `0th` bit must be set, for it to be a prime (except for 2).

Comment: Right, of course it is, I'm being dumb, lol. Time for a nap, it's 3:50 AM.